# Using Windows 10 IoT on Raspberry Pi 2 as RDP Gateway

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I am wanting to create an RDP Gateway for my house so I can RDP into a single device, and then RDP from that device to the device that I would like to access.

Is it possible to RDP to Windows 10 IoT installed on a Raspberry Pi 2 and then RDP out of it to another device on the local network?

Comment: Very unlikely. Windows 10 IoT is missing a lot of components you’d usually find in a Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

There are few tools you can use

- TeamViewer

  - Chrome rdp
  - ammyadmin
- Microsoft rdp client

Or you can configure vpn